# Avoid id(pk) overflow

Tags: sql, postgresql, activerecord

I'm developing a project on Ruby on Rails 4

I will need to import *billions* to *dozens of billions* of data into a datatable.

I'm not sure will there be a overflow problem ?

That is, the *id* column will be auto-incremental in most case

I'm afraid the column *id* will be overflow with large numbers,

like `278461278461`

If there will be a overflow problem in the column, how to fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of an integer (or serial), use a bigint (or bigserial). That will give you a max of  9223372036854775807 unique numeric id's.

Another option could be a UUID

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to display all the millions of records/rows to the user at once?

Datatable can handle millions of records/rows. But I would suggest you to do this server side and give clients as much low data as possible.

Comment: Hi I updated my question, That is, the id column will be auto-incremental in most case

I'm afraid the column id will be overflow with large numbers,